# What is the simplest undecidable formula of the First Order Logic (Predicate Logic)?

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic, decidability

What is the simplest undecidable formula of the First Order Logic (Predicate Logic). I would like to get a practical feeling of undecidability. I am aware of the book http://www.springer.com/la/book/9783540423249 in which all the decidable un undecidable fragments of the first order logic are classified but instead of reading the whole book I would like to go straight to one, simple, undecidable formula and see where is the root cause of undecidability>

Comment: What do you mean by "simplest"?

Comment: "Simplest" - maybe one with the smallest number of quantifiers and variables? I just wanted to see on undecidable formula and then I will feel what to do with it. Answer by Bram28 certainly provide whole new perspective in my question, but in essence at present I am not interested in subtleties of the theory, I just wanted to feel how it is to meet undecidable formula?

Comment: Then maybe you could consider an empty theory and a formula $(\exists x, y) \, x \neq y$ ?

Comment: No, I don't want empty theory. It could be better to have non-empty, finite theory.

Comment: Ok, then let $T = \{ (\exists x) \, x = x \}$ and the same formula.

Comment: My thesis is: "one can always remove undecidability by adding additional axiom, information or decision rule". It is how the human mind function when it meets undecidable situation - it goes out for additional information or makes some kind of assumption, then takes decision and then acts. I am glad that i have discovered it.

Comment: I think undecidability is inextricably bound up with the details (subtleties) of the theory. In addition there are undecided statements which may or may not be decidable. So in some contexts, if I am right about this, there may be a simplest known undecidable statement. Since "simplest" is a complex property I could imagine a context in which it would be undecidable whether the simplest known undecidable statement was in fact the simplest undecidable statement. I don't have enough FOL intuition to say this is within FOL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not *one* formula that is undecidable, unless you *fix* some kind of system that tries to decide formulas, and then it is possible that that formula will indeed stump that particular system.

That is: The undecidability of FOL means that relative to any one system that tries to figure out whether FOL formulas are valid or not, there will always be some formula that the system cannot decide on (assuming the system is sound and bound by the limits of Turing-computation)

But: for every *one* formula, there is *some*  system that is able to say that it is valid or invalid. This is trivial: Relative to any one formula $\varphi$, consider two systems: system $A$ is a system that answer 'valid' whenever it receives $\varphi$ on the input, but for any other input doesn't give any decision.  System $B$ is a system that answer 'invalid' whenever it receives $\varphi$ on the input, but for any other input doesn't give any decision. Now, given that $\varphi$ is either valid or invalid, one of these systems is sound, and makes the correct decision on $\varphi$. So, every *one* formula is decidable by some system.

So, to say that you have an undecidable formula only makes sense relative  to a specific system: if you point to such a system (and again, assuming it is sound), then one could point to some formula that is undecidable for that system, but it is not true that there is some formula that is undecidable, period.

Still, many systems that try to figure out whether some FOL formula is valid or not are programmed using similar algorithms, and indeed many such systems will fail on just about invalid formula whose only counterexamples are of infinite size (indeed, very crudely, one aspect of the 'root' of the problem of undecidability is *infinity* ... that there are infinitely many possible scenarios to consider).  Here is a fairly simple one:

$$\neg (\forall x\forall y\forall z((Rxy \land  Ryz)\rightarrow Rxz)\land \forall x \neg Rxx \land \forall x \exists y Rxy)$$

Comment: Thank you. How we can prove that FOL is undecidable thought it's satisfiable? Can you please give me a reference/YouTube link?

Comment: @Avv  I am not sure what you mean by FOL being satisfiable ... specific sets of FOL sentences can be satisfiable (or not), but I have never heard of FOL, as a logic system, being satisfiable.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please look into my question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4394083/find-worlds-and-or-context-associations-for-which-phi-does-not-hold-for-inter

Comment: Thank you. How we can show decidability please? Can you give easy and simple reference for starters? I have a bunch of problems where I am asked to check if they are decidable/undecidable, but not sure where to start?

Comment: @Avv  Hmm, I see that in that question you quantify over predicates, so this is no longer FOL, but higher-order logic, which I am unfortunately not too familiar with.  I also don't see what this has to do with undecidability .... Anyway, I am afraid that that question is beyond my expertise, sorry!

Comment: Thank you. Can you share easy to follow reference please about decidability?

Comment: Try this: http://www.cs.nmsu.edu/historical-projects/Projects/FoLundecidability.pdf

Comment: https://www.umsu.de/trees/  plug the formula here to see how the thing is undesirable